# VS Code JavaScript green lightbulb is not visible

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've read that VS Code is able to let me automatically setup jsconfig.json file. According to manual there should be a green lightbulb at the status bar (see the link below) & it should show up after I've created js file. Sadly it's not there for me. How can I make it visible?

I'm using the newest Code version (1.7.1) on Mac OS Sierra (10.12.1). I know I can create this file manually, but it would be awesome, if VS could do it for me, as described in VS Code manual. Thank you in advance for help.

EDIT: Here is the link to VS Code Manual & Adding jsconfig:

code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs#_adding-a-jsconfigjson-configuration-file

Comment: i see exactly the same (no lightbulb) on windows 10 - Code version 1.7.2

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing (no lightbulb). I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.1 and VS Code 1.7.2

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17154